# How to call .on('click') function from another function in JavaScript

Tags: function, call, conventions

I have two functions, first `$('#tabela').on('click', '.buyButton', function()` and second function `submitAll()` How can I call first function from the second?

Comment: give a name to the first function and call in the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

First function

```
function first() {
    $('#tabela').on('click', '.buyButton', function() {});
}
```

In Second function:

```
function submitAll() {        
    first();     
}
```

If `#tabela` is a button then use `onClick="first();"`

Answer (score 1):

Give the first function a name

```
function tabelaOnClick() {
    $('#tabela').on('click', '.buyButton', function() {});
}
```

Call it inside the second one

```
function submitAll() {
    ...
    tabelaOnClick();
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to click the button, you may just want to use `$('#tabela').click()`

If you want to fire the `onClick` event, better give the handle function a name, and call it from both `onClick` function and `submitAll` function.

Answer (score 1):

how about using `$('#tabela').trigger('click')` ?